# Adding transition to Side nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, nav

I have a site with a side navigation bar that is supposed to slide in via the right side, then when you close it, it transitions back into the side. When designing this i realized that after clicking the side bar once it overrides my style of "transition:0.5s" and instead just appears.

Here is my code

```
window.onclick = function(event){if(event.target == document.getElementById('outerNav')){closeNav();}};

function openNav() {
document.getElementById("outerNav").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("outerNav").style.transition = "0.5s";
document.getElementById("jrc-sidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("et-main-area").style.opacity = "0.7";
document.getElementById("jrc-sidenav-background").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.7)";
document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "none";

}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("jrc-sidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("et-main-area").style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById("jrc-sidenav-background").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("outerNav").style.display = "none";
},500);
}
```

```
.outerNav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```
<div id="outerNav" class="outerNav">
<div id="jrc-sidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
<form autocomplete="off" name="wpv-filter--TCPID247646" action="https://jrcstage.jr-staging.info/search-results/" method="get" class="wpv-filter-form js-wpv-filter-form js-wpv-filter-form--TCPID247646 js-wpv-form-full" data-viewnumber="-TCPID247646" data-viewid="" data-viewhash="W10=" data-viewwidgetid="0" data-orderby="" data-order="" data-orderbyas="" data-orderbysecond="" data-ordersecond="" data-parametric="{" query":"normal","id":null,"view_id":null,"widget_id":0,"view_hash":"-tcpid247646","action":"\="" test-quadmenu\="" ?wpv_view_count="-TCPID247646&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:{&quot;orderby&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;order&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orderby_as&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orderby_second&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;order_second&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;orderby&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;order&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orderby_as&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orderby_second&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;order_second&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;ajax_form&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;ajax_results&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;effect&quot;:&quot;fade&quot;,&quot;prebefore&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;before&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;after&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;attributes&quot;:[],&quot;environment&quot;:{&quot;current_post_id&quot;:247646,&quot;parent_post_id&quot;:0,&quot;parent_term_id&quot;:0,&quot;parent_user_id&quot;:0,&quot;archive&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[]}},&quot;loop&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[],&quot;id&quot;:0}}&quot;" data-attributes="[]" data-environment="{" current_post_id":247646,"parent_post_id":0,"parent_term_id":0,"parent_user_id":0,"archive":{"type":"","name":"","data":[]}}"=""><input type="hidden" class="js-wpv-dps-filter-data js-wpv-filter-data-for-this-form" data-action="https://jrcstage.jr-staging.info/search-results/" data-page="1" data-ajax="disable" data-effect="fade" data-maxpages="1" data-ajaxprebefore="" data-ajaxbefore="" data-ajaxafter=""><input class="wpv_view_count wpv_view_count--TCPID247646" type="hidden" name="wpv_view_count" value="-TCPID247646">

<div class="form-group search-page search">
  <div class="search-form-group-inner">
    <input type="text" name="wpv_post_search" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger-delayed filter-text-search form-control" placeholder="Search"><i class="fas fa-search" style="position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 54px;
    color: #aaaa;"></i>
<span style="display:none" class="js-wpv-dps-spinner"><img src="https://jrcstage.jr-staging.info/wp-content/plugins/wp-views/embedded/res/img/ajax-loader4.gif"></span>
<input type="submit" class="jrc-search-button wpv-submit-trigger js-wpv-submit-trigger btn" name="wpv_filter_submit" value="Search">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is your outer-nav. When you open the menu it got set to "display:block" - that happens without a transition.
If you also resize it from 0% to 100% with a transition, it should work. See the snippet:

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('outerNav')) {
    closeNav();
  }
};

function openNav() {

  document.getElementById("outerNav").style.position = "fixed";
  document.getElementById("outerNav").style.width = "100%"; //added this for opening the menu
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.getElementById("outerNav").style.width = "0%";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.outerNav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  /* 0% when Menu is closed */
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outerNav" class="outerNav">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
    <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey Mario, This works great for the first time you click it, however after clicking it more than once it goes back to no transition when opening the nav and just pops open!

Comment: I edited my answer - now it should work every time (got rid of the display:none/block stuff)

Comment: It works amazingly! Thank you so much for all your help!